# I'm looking for a paper or otherwise, released in 1963 by a certain "Young"

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, reference-request

Firstly, I'm sorry if this place is not where I should be asking questions like these.

In short, I'm looking for the paper which contains the result below in **topological graph theory** to cite.

This is all the information I have:

> Young, 1963:
>
> Every embedding of a connected graph G of genus g on the orientable surface $S_g$, $g \geq 0$ is a 2-cell embedding

Comment: Apparently cited as Theorem 3.8 on page 321 of Handbook of Combinatorics.

Comment: See also https://doi.org/10.1002/jgt.3190020402

Comment: @lhf Thank you, I found it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image][image]

Pretty sure this is the one you want.  https://www.jstor.org/stable/24900867?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps Gail S. Young, who co-authored a topology book that came out in 1962? Seems like a good place to look...